# Spark - Sort by key with type BytesWritable

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I want to do a benchmark and generated files using hadoop example RandomWriter. The type of the key and value are both BytesWritable. So how do I sort this file using Spark? Seems I cannot call sortByKey() directly.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Spark. Can you give me more detailed information?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to use a `.sortBy` method in an [`RDD`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD), right? That's why you cannot find the `.sortByKey` method of `OrderedRDDFunctions`.

As @JustinPihony points, this requires an implicit ordering of the key, which in this case (AFAIK) would be defined as:

```
implicit val randomWriterOrdering = new Ordering[RandomWriter] {
  def compare(a: RandomWriter, b: RandomWriter) = a compareTo b
}
```

Then you only need to extract the `RandomWriter` from your `RDD`, with the function that the documentation presents as `f: (T) ⇒ K`, as all the other parameters in the method have default values.

Well, that as far as I could understand. It is a good idea to add some small code snippet for context. For example the interface of a minimal function/method that cannot be implemented is usually useful.